# Cross-compile gmp in gcc from Android NDK, failed to execute ./gen-fac_ui

Tags: android, c, gcc, android-ndk, gmp

I'm building gcc for Android on CentOS using the cross-compile toolchain generated by running the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script in the Android NDK, and the gcc source files from the downloaded Android NDK toolchain sources.  The GMP sources were obtained by running the download_prerequisites script located in the gcc/contrib folder.

I've specified --build=x86_64-linux and --host=arm-linux-eabi, cross compile tools are set in the env variables, and specified when running configure.  I've run ../gcc-4.7/configure, then make -d.  Make fails when building gmp with /bin/sh. ./gen-fac_ui. Cannot execute binary.

The specific command is: ./gen-fac_ui $(BITS_PER_MP_LIMB) $(GMP_NAIL_BITS) >mpz/fac_ui.h || (rm -f mpz/fac_ui.h; exit 1)

I'm guessing the execution fails because I'm using cross-compile tools and the gen-fac_ui binary won't run on CentOS.  My question is:  **is there another way to generate mpz/fac_ui.h as a work around?**

I've also tried running make -d -i, which finishes successfully but seems to skip building key files...like gcc or g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:
I needed the native (i.e for CentOS) GCC tools to build and run gen-fac_ui.

Long Answer:
[This](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=27223) is my post at the OSDev forum, where I basically asked the same question and got an answer. It also contains my error (and correction) of not having glibc-devel installed for the 
native GCC toolchain.

In addition, since the base version of GCC for my build system was 4.4.7 and I was trying to cross-native build 4.7, I had to get the developer toolset, which can be installed via yum.  Information on the toolset is [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/) and easy install instructions are [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/User_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Install.html)

FWIW, I'm still not entirely sure how I was supposed to determine that gen-fac_ui needed to be made by a gcc native to the build machine...other than there was no other way I could find to generate fac_ui.h and other headers.